# Append Elements in Nav bar on button click and save the appended element to localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's [My code](https://plnkr.co/edit/6dVUBR0pSGqWmEM517Pa?p=preview)!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

<div id="myHeader">     
    <a style="float:left" href="index.html">Index</a>
    <a href="page1.html">Page1</a>
    <a href="page2.html">Page2</a>
</div>

<h1>Index</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

I am building my web application with the same navigation bar on the top of it for every web page. Now if you click on page1 in the nav bar on my example, you will see on the Page.html two buttons with add Prev and add Ext.

If you click on add Prev a page will append itself in the nav bar before page1.

If you click on add Ext a page will append itself in the nav bar after page1.

How can I save the appended Element for example page1-ext/page-prev to localStorage, so that when I navigate to page 2 or refresh the page it stays seen or appended!

I am thankful for every tip or solution! Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `window.localStorage.setItem` to set item in localStorage. Also, I moved `<script src="script.js"></script>` at the end of body because otherwise I get strange behaviors.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

    <div id="myHeader">     
        <a href="index.html">Index</a> 
        <a id="t1" href="page1.html">Page1</a>
        <a id="t2" href="page2.html">Page2</a>
    </div>

    <h1>Index</h1>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

page1.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

    <div id="myHeader">     
        <a href="index.html">Menu</a>
        <a id="t1" href="page1.html">Page1</a>
        <a id="t2" href="page2.html">Page2</a>
    </div>

    <h1>Page1</h1>
    <button id="addPrev"> Add Prev </button>
    <button id="addExt"> Add Ext </button>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

page2.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

    <div id="myHeader">     
        <a href="index.html">Menu</a>
        <a id="t1" href="page1.html">Page1</a>
        <a id="t2" href="page2.html">Page2</a>
    </div>

    <h1>Page2</h1>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js: moved all events in here (in one place). On button click, add content and also set localStorage item. When this file is loaded, checks if localStorage item is set (in this case, `== 1`). If so, then automatically display menu item:

```
$("#addPrev").on("click", function() {
    $('#1').after('<a href="page1-ext.html">Page1-Ext</a>');
    window.localStorage.setItem('previous', 1);
});

$("#addExt").on("click", function() {
    $('#1').after('<a href="page1-ext.html">Page1-Ext</a>');
    window.localStorage.setItem('next', 1);
});

if (window.localStorage.getItem('previous') == 1) {
    $('#t1').before('<a href="page1-prev.html">Page1-Prev</a>');
}

if (window.localStorage.getItem('next') == 1) {
    $('#t1').before('<a href="page1-prev.html">Page1-Prev</a>');
}
```

However, one (negative) thing to note, you'll have to write `<a id="t1" href="page1.html">Page1</a>` and `<a id="t2" href="page2.html">Page2</a>` in every page to show these menu links, otherwise, you won't see them.

Comment: You are the man of the day!!! can i contact you directly if have other questions? I am doing now my thesis :(

Comment: @Bratan I'm glad my answer solved your problem! You can contact me (info is in profile). It's up to you :)

Comment: please check your Email :)